# C linked lists allocating memory

Tags: c, linked-list

```
struct Node
{
 int val;
 struct Node *next;
};
struct List
{
 struct Node *head;
 struct Node *tail;
 int size;
};
typedef struct List *List;
```

I have this Linked List created, when i try to allocate memory for the head program crashes

```
List Test;
Test->head = (struct Node *) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
```

Comment: Pointers must be initialized to valid address before dereferenced. Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Where does `Test` point to?

Comment: Do not hide pointer nature behind typedefs.  It is more likely to confuse than to help.

Answer (score 1):

`Test` is just a pointer. it does not point to anywhere. it may be NULL or point to any random address.
you have to allocate some memory in order to use it:

- `List Test = malloc(sizeof(Struct List));`
  this option will allocated dynamic struct and Test will point to it.
- `Struct List Test = {0};`
  This option will use a struct on the stack

Comment: `Struct` with a capital `S`? Also how do you know there is even a `struct List`?

Comment: it is taken out of the code

Comment: OK, but Struct with a capital S is still wrong

Comment: I agree. I would use 'list_t'